# Unable to make changes to /etc

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I am using embedded linux (built using LTIB).

I am unable to make changes to `/etc` directory. Basically I want to add a start-up script to `/etc/rc.d/init.d`

`/etc/` seems to be mounted as rwfs

output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 3.0G    376.9M      2.4G  13% /
tmpfs                   424.2M     36.0K    424.1M   0% /dev
shm                     424.2M         0    424.2M   0% /dev/shm
rwfs                    376.0M      5.1M    370.9M   1% /mnt/rwfs
rwfs                    376.0M      5.1M    370.9M   1% /tmp
rwfs                    376.0M      5.1M    370.9M   1% /var
rwfs                    376.0M      5.1M    370.9M   1% /etc
```

I have tried :

```
umount /etc/ 
touch /etc/dummy  --> just for the sake of checking
reboot
(after boot-up)
ls -lth /etc/dummy ---> file is missing
```

This is an image which I boot from an SD card. On one of the SD cards, after I did the above `umount /etc`, and then placed a dummy file as mentioned above, on the next boot as expected `/etc` goes back to be mounted as `tmpfs` but the dummy file was available. But on another SD card when I try the same, dummy file is not available.

Any suggestions?

Output of `mount` (before using `umount /etc/`):

```
root@freescale /etc$ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
rwfs on /mnt/rwfs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
rwfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
rwfs on /var type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
rwfs on /etc type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
```

Output of mount (after `umount /etc`):

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
rwfs on /mnt/rwfs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
rwfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
rwfs on /var type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
```

Comment: have you tried `mount -o remount,rw /etc`?

Comment: @EugenRieck: Yes I have tried, it comes back saying     "mount: can't find /etc in /proc/mounts"

Comment: Please ask a specific question. "Any suggestions?" is not specific. My answer assumes the real question is "why?" See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This line from the output of `mount`

```
rwfs on /etc type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=385024k)
```

says `/etc` is in fact `tmpfs`. Now from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs):

> `tmpfs` is a common name for a temporary file storage facility on many Unix-like operating systems. It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device.

And

> Everything stored in `tmpfs` is temporary in the sense that no files will be created on the hard drive; however, swap space is used as backing store in case of low memory situations. On reboot, everything in `tmpfs` will be lost.

This is exactly what happens in your case.

Embedded systems use `tmpfs` for `/etc` and few other directories to make them writable for any program that needs it, but in the same time

- to avoid filesystem corruption when any writing is in progress and the device is powered off by pulling the plug;
- to avoid OS corruption when you do something wrong by playing in the console.

"Big" systems may be rescued by booting from USB, running `fsck` etc. Here it's highly desirable to just restart with verified configuration.

In general the OS may provide a way to commit changes, write them to a non-volatile memory from where they will be restored at the next reboot. Or it may neither provide a way nor such restoration process at all.

Comment: this is an image which I boot from an sd card. On one of the sd card, after I did 'umount /etc', and then placed a dummy file inside it. On the next boot 'etc' goes back to be mounted as tmpfs but the dummy file was available. But on another sd card when I try the same, it doesn't work.

Comment: @kman What is your point? Note I don't know details of your embedded system, e.g. how it populates `/etc` after mounting `tmpfs` there.

Comment: Just added my above comment to the description above - just to ensure I have described the problem fully. What is not clear at this point is - as you say "In general the OS may provide a way to commit changes, write them to a non-volatile memory from where they will be restored at the next reboot. Or it may neither provide a way nor such restoration process at all." --- how is this working on one sd card but not on the other.

Comment: @kman My bet is you did something in a different way.